# Concern regarding automation using Protractor

Tags: automation, protractor

Am new to protractor. I found some errors while automating the URL using protractor. And I can access the URL manually and does not find any issues. Please find the code mentioned below and kindly clarify my concern.
Screenshot of cmd while executing the code

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR8bK.png]

```
exports.config={
          specs: ['try.js'],
          //seleniumArgs: ['-browserTimeout=60']
        capabilities:{
        'browserName':'chrome', 
        },
          baseUrl:'',
          allScriptsTimeout:3000,
          //getPageTimeout:5000,
          framework:'jasmine2',
          jasmineNodeOpts: {
              defaultTimeoutInterval:56000,
              isVerbose: true,
                           }

          }
spec: try.js
===========
describe('first try',function(){
    var EW=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
       beforeEach(function(done){
    ignoreSynchronization=true;
        browser.get('');

     });

   it('open PO',function(){
       //clicking login button
      var login=element(by.linkText('Login'));
      browser.wait(EW.presenceOf(login),10000);
      login.click();
       //clicking open Po dashboard icon/link
      var po=element(by.linkText('Open PO'));
       browser.wait(EW.presenceOf(po),20000);
       po.click();
     //entering value 100 in the fiter field
    var e=element.all(by.repeater('colFilter in col.filters')).get(00).element(by.tagName('input'));
    browser.wait(EW.presenceOf(e),10000);
    e.sendKeys(100);

    //selecting the filterd values and printing it in console

   element.all(by.repeater('col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid').column('Entity')).getText().then(console.log);

  });
});
```

Comment: Code? Also, don't screenshot it just paste the format the relevant code.

Comment: Is this an angular site under test? If yes, where `ng-app` is defined. Also, show your protractor config and the actual test code.

Comment: Base url is removed since it is accessible from VPN

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have ng-app defined on all of your pages. Protractor requires it to run. If the page has redirects or just takes some time before it loads, try something like this:

```
browser.get(websiteUrl);
browser.wait(function () {
    return browser.executeScript('return !!window.angular');
}, 10000, 'Error: Angular was not found on the page within ten seconds');
```

This will wait up to ten seconds for angular to load up, and fail if it is not there.